# print pdf with sunmi flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf

I created invoice pdf with this plugin **pdf: ^3.10.4** and want to use this plugin **sunmi_printer_plus: ^2.1.01** to print invoice in sunmi, to use this i want to convert pdf to image when try that invoice show as this [invoice output on sunmi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UXaT.jpg)
this is code of generate pdf

```
class PdfInvoiceApi {
  static Future<Document> generate( Pump_Transactions pump) async {
    final pdf = Document();
    final font= await rootBundle.load("lib/fonts/HacenTunisia.ttf");
    final ttf= Font.ttf(font);
    double fontSize10=12;
    double fontSize12=14;

    pdf.addPage(Page(
        theme: ThemeData.withFont(
          base: ttf,
        ),
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.roll80,
        build: (Context context) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Divider(),
                    if(pump.name != null && pump.name!.length>0)
                      Directionality(
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                  'فاتورة ضريبية ', style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: fontSize12,
                              ))
                          )
                      ),
                    if(pump.name == null || pump.name!.isEmpty)
                    Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                'فاتورة ضريبية مبسطة ', style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: fontSize12,
                            ))
                        )
                    ),
                    Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                CompanyData.companyData!.name!, style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: fontSize12,
                            ))
                        )
                    ),
                    Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                'رقم ضريبى : '+CompanyData.companyData!.taxNumber!, style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: fontSize12,
                            ))
                        )
                    ),
                    Divider(),

                    Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        child:  Text(
                            'رقم الفاتورة :'+ pump.bill!.transaction!.toString(), style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: fontSize10,
                        )
                        )
                    ),
                    Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        child:  Text(
                                'التاريخ :'+ pump.bill!.dateTime!, style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: fontSize10,
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        child:  Text(
                            'العنوان :'+CompanyData.companyData!.address!, style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: fontSize10,
                        )
                        )
                    ),
                    Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        child:  Text(
                            'الفرع :'+CompanyData.companyData!.branch!, style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: fontSize10,
                        )
                        )
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    if(pump.name != null && pump.name!.length>0)
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.end ,
                        children:
                          [
                            Directionality(
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                child:  Text(
                                    'اسم العميل :'+ pump.name!.toString(), style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: fontSize10,
                                )
                                )
                            ),
                            Directionality(
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                child:  Text(
                                    'العنوان :'+ pump.address!, style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: fontSize10,
                                )
                                )
                            ),
                            Directionality(
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                child:  Text(
                                    'الرقم الضريبي :'+pump.tax_number!, style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: fontSize10,
                                )
                                )
                            ),
                            Divider(),
                          ]
                      ),
                    Container(
                     // margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(22, 5, 22, 5),
                      child: Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        child: Table.fromTextArray(
                          headerStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12
                          ),
                          headers: <dynamic>['الإجمالي', 'السعر' ,'الكمية باللتر ', 'الصنف'],
                          cellAlignment: Alignment.center,
                          cellStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12
                          ),
                          data:  <List<dynamic>>[
                            <dynamic>[pump.bill!.amount!.toStringAsFixed(2), pump.bill!.price!.toStringAsFixed(2) ,pump.bill!.volume, pump.bill!.productName ],
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        child:  Text('الإجمالي : '+pump.bill!.amount!.toStringAsFixed(2)+" ريال ", style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: fontSize10,
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        child:  Text('الضريبة : '+(CompanyData.companyData!.tax!*100).toStringAsFixed(0)+"%  "+
          (  pump.bill!.amount!-  (pump.bill!.amount! / (1 + CompanyData.companyData!.tax!))).toStringAsFixed(2)+" ريال ", style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: fontSize10,
                        )
                        ),

                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    Center(
                      child:
                      BarcodeWidget(
                          data: pump.qr!,
                          barcode: Barcode.qrCode(),
                        //  width: 200,
                          height: 150
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 15.0)
                  ]
              )
          ;
        }
    ));
    return pdf;
  }


}
```

this code to print pdf on sunmi

```
final pdfFile = await PdfInvoiceApi.generate(pump);
Uint8List bytes=await pdfFile.save();
await SunmiPrinter.bindingPrinter();
await SunmiPrinter.initPrinter();
await SunmiPrinter.startTransactionPrint(true);
await SunmiPrinter.setAlignment(SunmiPrintAlign.CENTER);
 await SunmiPrinter.printImage(bytes!);
 await SunmiPrinter.lineWrap(10);
 await SunmiPrinter.submitTransactionPrint();
 await SunmiPrinter.exitTransactionPrint(true);
```

and try this also not print anything

```
      final pdfFile = await PdfInvoiceApi.generate(pump);
       await for (var page in Printing.raster(await pdfFile.save(), pages: [0, 1], dpi: 72)) {
   final image = await page.toPng();
   bytes=image; 
   await SunmiPrinter.bindingPrinter();
   await SunmiPrinter.initPrinter();               
   await SunmiPrinter.startTransactionPrint(true);
   await SunmiPrinter.setAlignment(SunmiPrintAlign.CENTER);
   await SunmiPrinter.printImage(bytes!);
   await SunmiPrinter.lineWrap(10);
   await SunmiPrinter.submitTransactionPrint();
   await SunmiPrinter.exitTransactionPrint(true);}
```

so how can print pdf on sunmi please